# New object, but error: an object with the same key already exists in the objectstatemanager. the objectstatemanager cannot track multiple (...)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many, objectcontext

`Student` and `Teacher` are i relationship `many-to-many`.

When I have `Student` existed in database, and want to add new `Teacher`, I try code below.

But in line:
`addedTeachers.ForEach(a => dbStudent.Teacher.Add(a));` I get error

"`an object with the same key already exists in the objectstatemanager. the objectstatemanager cannot track multiple objects with the same key`".

What's wrong?

```
void Update(Student s)
{
    using(var context = new MyEntities(connectionString))
    {
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var dbStudent = context.Student.Include("Teacher").Where(a => a.Id == s.Id).SingleOrDefault();

        var dbTeachers = dbStudent.Teacher.ToList();
        var newTeachers = s.Teacher.ToList();

        var addedTeachers = newTeachers.Except(dbTeachers).ToList();
        var deletedTeachers = dbTeachers.Except(newTeachers).ToList();

        addedTeachers.ForEach(a => dbStudent.Teacher.Add(a));
        deletedTeachers.ForEach(a => dbStudent.Teacher.Remove(a));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

What's strange else:

just before this line with exception `dbStudent.Teacher.Count` is 0. But after exception is 1. Of course `addedTeachers.Count` is also 1, but debugger doesn't reach the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `s` and `dbStudent` has the same primary key. Your `Teacher` instances in `s.Teacher` collection may refer to the `s` instance. Then when you call `addedTeachers.ForEach(a => dbStudent.Teacher.Add(a));`, EF will identity all objects linked to teacher instance and try to add them too.

Try

```
addedTeachers.ForEach(a => { a.Students.Remove(s);
                             a.Students.Add(dbStudent);
                             dbStudent.Teacher.Add(a);});
```

Comment: Can you look at my second very similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354046/add-item-and-update-relationship-in-transitional-table-in-many-to-many-database

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390) statement. It is comparing your collection items using the `Default` comparer which is comparing to see if the items reference the same object in memory when you actually intend it to compare the values of your Teacher objects.

The solution is to provide your own `IEqualityComparer` and specify exactly how the `Teacher` objects should be compared to each other. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390) provides a good example of how to do this.

Comment: No, I have my own comparer Except extension and it works good. Furthermore there's no other Teacher in database or memory. Now is only one that I want to add...