# Add item and update relationship in transitional table in many-to-many database Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many, entityobject

--here was wrong model without association manyTOmany between A-B. corrected is in EDIT2--

`A` exists in database, `B` exists in database.
I need only enter new `C` element with some Properties1 and Properties2 (and update collections of `C` in existed `A` and `B` elements)

I tried many options, like for example this, but still somethings wrong (with ObjectOCntext and existed Key etc)

```
void SaveNewC(C newC)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities(connectionString))
    {
        var dbA = context.A.Where(a => a.Id == newC.A.Id).SingleOrDefault();
        var dbB = context.B.Where(b => b.Id == newC.B.Id).SingleOrDefault();

        newC.A = dbA;
        newC.B = dbB;
        context.AddObject(newC);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Exception that I get: `"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."`

**EDIT2**
updated model

[image]

Comment: Can you post the entire exception you're getting?

Comment: Don't have `A` and `B` navigation collections refering to each other? You cannot have a many-to-many relationship without navigation properties. It's also important to know if and how those collections are populated in `newC.A` and `newC.B`.

Comment: @Slauma You're right. Last time I improve model incorrect without navigtion properties. Now model is fully cmplete

Comment: Try to clear all references in `newC.A` and `newC.B`: `newC.A.C = null; newC.A.B.Clear();` and `newC.B.C = null; newC.B.A.Clear();` and check if it works then.

Comment: @Slauma Yes, I tried it before, but still the same exception

Comment: There must be something more which is not visible in your example code. If all those references are cleared this exception is impossible.

Comment: Your model seems really confusing.  You have a Many to Many on A -> B which is being mapped, I assume with C.  Why do you need to have the C entity at all?  EF will automatically hide the junction table away and manage that.  If you're planning on having custom logic on C then you should no longer have the Many to Many directly from A->B, but it should go A -> C -> B instead. Otherwise you've created another hidden away junction table (D maybe?)  Is this what you intended to do?

Comment: @Slauma I flag this topic to moderator to remove. See more actual version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372975/many-to-many-with-junction-table-in-entity-framework

Comment: What are you doing :( That's the same question as this one and still this mysterious exception...

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Entry(dbA).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
context.Entry(dbB).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
context.AddObject(newC);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: There's no "State" property in EntityObject

Comment: If you mean `context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(dbA, System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);` I tried it, but I get InvalidOperationException: "`An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`" - but C object is new one

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your `newC` has already populated navigation properties `A` and `B` with the correct `Id`s. Then you can just attach the entities refered by the navigation properties to the context:

```
void SaveNewC(C newC)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities(connectionString))
    {
        context.A.Attach(newC.A);
        context.B.Attach(newC.B);

        context.C.AddObject(newC);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: While `context.A.Attach(newC.A);` I get exception: `"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."`

Comment: @Saint: Is the code in your question really complete? The first line above happens in a new context, so this context is empty and nothing can't be attached to it before this line. The only reason I could imagine is that `newC.A` has references to other objects and some of these objects in the graph are of the same type and have the same key but are different objects. Does `newC.A` have references to other entities?

Comment: Yes, A and B are in relationship many-to-many. I forgot to add this association at first time. See my EDIT2

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have the junction table mapped? If all your wanting is a Many to Many from A->B  you could do it in a simpler way.

If you created the C table as a true junction - and have a FK to A and B set to it's PK in sql like this:

[image]

Then when you create your edmx from the model it will create this:

[image]

Now, in your code if you wanted to add a relationship, you would simply add it to your collection, and EF will automatically create the relationship in your C table for you:

```
        var A = new A();
        var b = new B();
        var b2 = new B();

        A.B.Add(b);
        A.B.Add(b2);
```

Comment: No, I need this junction table

Comment: See more actual version of this topic, this one will be removed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372975/many-to-many-with-junction-table-in-entity-framework